# neo4j find parent node is relationship exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to develop a product like a google drive. This is the second phase now. I am stuck in making cypher query and I need help.

a user A can share a file/folder with a group or another user B.

case 1: user A, shared the folder which consists of other subfolders. user B would see the shared folder. however, now user A shared a subfolder, and again user B should see only the root folder.

case 2: user A, shared the only subfolder then, user B will only see a shared subfolder

basically I need to traverse the node from bottom to its parent and their parent with CAN_ACCESS_DIR relationship if any and stop at the first node with this relationship

please help

attached [image]image scenario -> 
find the root (JAVA) of JAVA2 and check if it has been shared (CAN_ACCESS_DIR) with the same group or a user. If yes, then we will send only the JAVA folder. If not then send only JAVA2 folder

```
match (g:group) where g.name = "group1" 
match p = (d:directory { name: "JAVA2"})<-[:LEAF | CONTAINS*0..]-(a:directory) where (d)<-[:CAN_ACCESS_DIR]-(g)
unwind nodes(p) as i
return collect(distinct(i)) as result

match (u:user) where u.name = "John"
match (t:tower) where t.name = "Genome"
match (d:directory) where d.name = "Root"
match (u)-[:MEMBER_OF_GROUP]->(g:group)
match (d)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(s) where (s)<-[:CAN_ACCESS_DIR]-(g)<-[:MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(u)
```

not an expert in neo4j, please guide me out. thanks

Comment: This is essentially the same question you already asked yesterday. You should have either updated that question, or deleted it before creating this one. I have closed the other one as a duplicate, as this version seems to be more clear.

Comment: Are you trying to get the group-accessible directory that is closest to the root, starting at a given (sub)directory?

Comment: yes, i need to access the closet to root one if it has can_access_relation

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

This query should return the group-accessible `a` directory that is closest to the root, starting at a specific (sub)directory:

```
MATCH p=(g:group)-[:CAN_ACCESS_DIR]->(d:directory)<-[:CONTAINS*0..]-(a)
WHERE g.name = "group1" AND d.name = "JAVA2"
MATCH (a)<-[:CAN_ACCESS_DIR]-(g)
RETURN p, a
ORDER BY LENGTH(p) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Since a single `MATCH` clause would filter out multiple uses of the same relationship, this query uses 2 `MATCH` clauses to allow the same `CAN_ACCESS_DIR` relationship to match twice, in case `d` is the only accessible directory (and therefore the same as `a`).

Comment: thx, it failing, if a group can access only JAVA folder which is the root

Comment: See my updated answer. I assume you would use "d.name = JAVA" instead of "d.name = JAVA2" to verify.